ERROR -- : Can't add attachment, no test, step or fixture is running (allure-rspec)
I'm integrating allure reports with my API test project using Rspec.
I wanted to attach request and response details to the report after each testcase.

The following is my response_parser to get needed request and response details.

module ResponseParser
  extend self

  def get_request_body(response)
    request_body = response[:request].body
    puts "#{request_body.class}"
    request_body
  end

  def get_request_headers(response)
    headers = []
    response[:request].each_header do |header, value|
      headers << "#{header}: #{value}"
    end
    puts "#{headers.class}"
    headers
  end

  def get_request_method(response)
    request_method = response[:request].method
    puts "#{request_method.class}"
    request_method
  end

  def get_request_uri(response)
    request_uri = response[:request].uri
    puts "#{request_uri.class}"
    request_uri
  end

  def get_response_body(response)
    response_body = JSON.parse(response[:response].body)
    puts "#{response_body.class}"
    response_body
  end

  def get_response_headers(response)
    headers = []
    response[:response].each_header do |header, value|
      headers << "#{header}: #{value}"
    end
    puts "#{headers.class}"
    headers
  end

  def get_response_status(response)
    {
      code: response[:response].code.to_i,
      message: response[:response].message
    }
  end
end

and I created an allure_helper to any customizations to the report
# spec/allure_helper.rb

require "allure-rspec"
require_relative '../lib/response_parser'

module AllureHelper
  extend self

  def attach_request_details_to_report(response)
    Allure.add_attachment(
      name: 'request method',
      source: ResponseParser.get_request_method(response),
      type: Allure::ContentType::TXT,
      test_case: true
    )

    Allure.add_attachment(
      name: 'request uri',
      source: ResponseParser.get_request_uri(response),
      type: Allure::ContentType::TXT,
      test_case: true
    )

    Allure.add_attachment(
      name: 'request headers',
      source: ResponseParser.get_request_headers(response).join("\n"),
      type: Allure::ContentType::TXT,
      test_case: true
    )

    Allure.add_attachment(
      name: 'request body',
      source: ResponseParser.get_request_body(response).to_json,
      type: Allure::ContentType::JSON,
      test_case: true
    )

    Allure.add_attachment(
      name: 'response status',
      source: ResponseParser.get_response_status(response).to_json,
      type: Allure::ContentType::JSON,
      test_case: true
    )

    Allure.add_attachment(
      name: 'response headers',
      source: ResponseParser.get_response_headers(response).join("\n"),
      type: Allure::ContentType::TXT,
      test_case: true
    )

    Allure.add_attachment(
      name: 'response body',
      source: ResponseParser.get_response_body(response).to_json,
      type: Allure::ContentType::JSON,
      test_case: true
    )

    rescue StandardError => e
      puts "Failed to add allure attachment: #{e.message}"
      puts e.backtrace
      example.execution_result.exception = e
  end
end

And the below in my spec_helper where I call the function to attach details to report in the after(:each) hook.
require "rspec"
require "allure-rspec"
require "pathname"

require_relative '../spec/allure_helper'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.add_formatter AllureRspecFormatter

  AllureRspec.configure do |c|
    c.results_directory = 'reports/allure-results'
    c.clean_results_directory = true
    c.logger = Logger.new($stdout, Logger::DEBUG)
    c.logging_level = Logger::INFO
  end

  config.after(:each) do |example|
    if @response
      example.metadata[:response] = @response
      AllureHelper.attach_request_details_to_report(@response)
    end
  end

  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end

  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end

  config.shared_context_metadata_behavior = :apply_to_host_groups
end

when I run tests, I keep getting this error
 ERROR -- : Can't add attachment, no test, step or fixture is running
I suspected the problem of calling the attach function in the after each hook and tried to call it inside the test just before the assertion but the same error happened.
 it 'returns success status code with correct username and password' do
      @response = Authentication.authenticate("admin", "password123")
      AllureHelper.attach_request_details_to_report(@response)
      assert_status_ok(@response)
    end


Could you please provide a sample repo to reproduce the problem? You can use this example as a baseline: https://github.com/allure-examples/allure-rspec-example, fork it and make the necessary changes
